# Table extraction from image based documents

Tags: image, ocr, document, boundary, abbyy

Is there any efficient algorithm/technique for extracting tables from image-based documents. We also have Abbyy OCR output in the form of XML which has coordinate information of the text in the document. We need to solve 2 major problems:

1. Identifying the table in the document. (Table structure is not fixed. Can have different layouts with or without bounding lines)
2. Extracting the text from the tables.

Comment: We need to extract the text in the table separated by rows and columns. Actually, tables are not always bounded by horizontal or vertical lines. We need to extract information from the tables which can be in multiple formats. The table format is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

- Get the xml file of the document.
- Start iterating the row elements in xml.
- Add the contents to a list.
- Convert the list to DataTable.

```
XmlNodeList xmlList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("page");
foreach(XmlNode xn in XmlList)
{
    foreach(XmlNode Xr in xn.ChildNodes)
    {
        if(Xr.Name ="row")
        {
            string rowvalue = xr.InnerText;
            youlist.Add(rowvalue);
        }
    }
}
```